# Converting multiple spark dataframe columns to a single column with list type

Tags: pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe like below.

```
Time           A      B     C     D

06:37:14       2      3     4     5
```

And I want to convert it to like this for all the rows. I don't want to use Pandas to get this done. The new column type should be a list type.

```
Time             Features

06:37:14        [2,3,4,5]
```

How can I do this using Pyspark?

Comment: If you have a predefined amount of columns, you can simply concatenate the values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have described in the comment, when you have a fixed number of columns, which you know in advance you can simply combine the values in a new column with `withColumn` and if you want an array you can use `array`

```python
df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("06:37:14", '2', '3', '4', '5')], ['Time', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df1.withColumn("Features", array("A","B","C","D")).drop("A","B","C","D").show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```python
+--------+------------+
|Time    |Features    |
+--------+------------+
|06:37:14|[2, 3, 4, 5]|
+--------+------------+
```